# Stub chained function call yields NullPointerException

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

In my Spring Boot project, I have test, I would like to stub a chained function call.

The function call to be tested is:

```
private String sniffPayload(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        return request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
```

In my unit test, I use Mockito to mock the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

@MockBean
private HttpServletRequest mockedRequest;
```

Then, in my test function:

```
    @Test
    void testMyFunction() throws Exception {

     // I try to stub the function return 
     // But get NullPointerException at runtime

 when(mockedRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))).thenReturn("FooBarData");

    ...
    }
```

When I run the test, I got `NullPointerException` for the line of code doing the stubbing `when(mockedRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))).thenReturn("FooBarData");`

Why? How can I get rid of this `NullPointerException` while stubbing the chained function return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik `@MockBean` does not create `deep stub mocks`, which means there is no support for chaining of mock calls.

Such your problem is that `mockedRequest.getReader()` returns null.

You can either switch to use mockito only
 (if you do not require any autowiring and whatnot /
 which imho does not seem to be relevant in the case of `HttpServletRequest`)

```java
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

Else you'll have to provide different mocks for every method called.

```java
Stream stream = Mockito.mock(Stream.class);
when(stream.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))).thenReturn("FooBarData");

BufferedReader reader = Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
when(reader.lines()).thenReturn(stream);

when(mockedRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(reader)
```

Mocking a stream is quite ugly, so instead you might want to replace that part with a real stream that provides the matching answer instead.

For example:

```java
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("FooBarData");

when(reader.lines()).thenReturn(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, how to `replace that part with a real stream`?

Comment: In reality, the data is in Json format like this `{"name": "John", "age": 26, "address":"foo", ...}` If I want to use this real data in test, do I need to add each json key-value to the `list`? Or should I add the whole json string as one element to the `list`?

Comment: As long as the end result (which is only one string) is the same it shouldn't matter how you add it ;). In the end you should (already) know how the format looks like, so you could just return it in the correct format.

Comment: Yes, I want to check some field inside payload in the interceptor. But I just verified that I can just add the whole json to the `list`, the code under test is able to get each key-value in json :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update the example There is actually a `Stream` class to create `Stream`'s directly out of `String`'s. No need for the workaround with the list.